# Modify chicago bst to include "in" before journal title

Tags: bibliographies, chicago-style

We are using the chicago bst and need to change the reference style to the International Labour Organization, which has some very strange requirements.  Here is the one we're working on now

> Currie, J.; Fallick, B.C. 1996. "The minimum wage and the employment
>   of youth: Evidence from the NLSY" , in Journal of Human Resources,
>   Vol. 31, No. 2, pp. 404–428.

In the MWE below everything is working well except for the "in" before the Journal of Human Resources which we cannot figure out how to insert.  We don't post the whole BST file but used questions 122768 163000 213837 157045 to modify the bst to get as far as we have.

```
\documentclass[twoside,14pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{CuF96,
author = {Currie, J. and Fallick, B.C.},
year={1996},
title={The minimum wage and the employment of youth: {E}vidence from the {NLSY}},
journal={Journal of Human Resources},
volume={31},
Number={2}, 
pages = {404–428}}
\end{filecontents} 
\begin{document}
Since a common result in impact assessments is that the poorest receive 
limited benefits  \citep{CuF96} 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{mychicago} % altered bst file.
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are a few "chicago" `.bst`s on CTAN. Could you be a little more specific about which one `mychicago.bst` is derived from?

Comment: I can spot at least ten [yes, 10!] differences in the format you (or, rather, ILO style) require and the format that's provided by the `chicago` bst file (which is based on ed. 13 of the CMoS). The presence or absence of the "In" prefix in front of the journal name is just one of them. Rather than hack an existing bib style file, you may be much better off creating a brand-new, bespoke bibliography style using the `makebst` utility.

Comment: Incidentally, `14pt` is not an option recognized by the `article` document class. In consequence, your document will end up being typeset at the default font size value, which is `10pt`.

Comment: It follows `B' reference style of the 13th Edition of  the Chicago Manual of Style.  Version 4 28 Aug 1992.

Comment: We would love to create a bespoke file, and tried to...didn't even really know how to get started.   Went to the directory where makebst was in terminal and type latex makebst and it says -bash: latex: command not found.  makebst is there in the right directory, but somehow we can  Worked on this for hours and got nowhere.  Most of the hacks are now in the mychicago.  It is just this last one.

Comment: Is `biblatex` an option?  It prints`in` by default and the standard question is usually how to remove it!